# Docker mapped port doesn't show up on "netstat", "ss" and "lsof"

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, docker, namespace, network-namespaces

I've a question about docker containers and sockets. Today i've discovered that, docker containers with mapped port `-p 80:80` (or etc ports) on the host system, doesn't show up when i use `netstat`, `ss` or `lsof -i` (also tried with `sudo`, no chance). Then i tried to test, open a listener port 80 with `sudo nc -l -p 80`, but no chance, it refused to connect port 80, although this port doesn't show up opened by some process.

I think this problem occurs due to containerization or network namespaces, but there should be some commands to list used sockets by low level, kernel level?

p.s: When I tried to use docker host network interface ip address on port mapping (`-p 172.17.0.1:80:80`), it showed up using above commands.

p.s-2: `lsof | grep -w 80` output:

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
Xorg        718                             root   37u      CHR              13,80       0t0      10891 /dev/input/event16
Xorg        718   749 Xorg:disk             root   37u      CHR              13,80       0t0      10891 /dev/input/event16
Xorg        718   778 Xorg:disk             root   37u      CHR              13,80       0t0      10891 /dev/input/event16
Xorg        718   787 Xorg:disk             root   37u      CHR              13,80       0t0      10891 /dev/input/event16
Xorg        718   841 InputThre             root   37u      CHR              13,80       0t0      10891 /dev/input/event16
```

Comment: What does docker inspect say? is it using bridge mode or is it actually providing a complete new IP address?

Comment: Perhaps the port is routed. Since no local process listens on it no process is shown.

Comment: Can you see the mapped port by something like `lsof | grep -w 80` (as root)?

Comment: @TheresaForster , i've uploaded the inspect reults here: https://ctxt.io/2/AABAtIUXEg

Comment: @Ned64, i've used "lsof -i" command to show listening ports, but no luck, it is not listed there. Only ipv6 listening port 80 shows there owned by docker

Comment: @SafarSafarli I did not mean the `-i` option, please try without.

Comment: @Ned64, here is it: https://imgur.com/EWXo0r6

Comment: @SafarSafarli Please do not reference external sources in your Question because they can be deleted. Edit your Question to include these details because it should be self-contained. Also, do not use images to represent text because images cannot be searched for text content (search function on SE).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98461/discussion-between-safar-safarli-and-ned64).

Comment: @Ned64, I've updated question.

Comment: The inspect information is missing, can you please edit your post and add the contents to the original question. Thanks, Also when you build the image have you added EXPORT 80 on the dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

Docker makes the system behave as a router between outside and the running containers: a router doesn't use sockets to perform routing (only for its own services or accessing remote services). That's why container connections don't appear with `netstat` or `ss`. With `lsof` they fail to appear for a similar reason: while `lsof` can display container's running processes and determine some of its file descriptors are sockets, it will fail to associate a socket within the local network stack's sockets (since they are in an other network namespace) so will fail to discover what these sockets really are.

The only case where Docker can create local sockets for its containers is when it's running with the option to use the `docker-proxy` process to handle [NAT hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback). The more recent default configuration doesn't use this anymore, because it can all be handled with *iptables*.

Docker also usually performs NAT. To do this it relies on *iptables* and *Netfilter*'s *conntrack* to memorize the NAT associations. The *conntrack* entries can be queried with the [`conntrack`](https://manpages.debian.org/conntrack/conntrack.8.en.html) tool (usually available in a package named `conntrack` or `conntrack-tools`).

For Docker's default mode: NAT, it's very easy to know traffic behind Docker. Any entry where the reply destination is different from the query source means a SNAT (incl MASQUERADE) was performed. Any *conntrack* entry where the reply source is different from the query destination means a DNAT (incl REDIRECT) was performed. `conntrack` can do this with adequate options:

```
conntrack -L --src-nat
conntrack -L --dst-nat
conntrack -L --any-nat
```

The first would usually show outgoing connection associations from containers to outside which are being MASQUERADE-d. The second would usually show incoming connection associations from outside to the containers which are being DNAT-ed, the 3rd would show everything. Of course, one can add more filters.

Using `-E` instead of `-L` can monitor such associations in event mode.

Of course if Docker is configured to not perform NAT, *conntrack* is still used for stateful firewalling so just not providing any filter option will still display sources and destinations.

Then for any IP address belonging to container namespace's addresses (eg typically 172.17.0.0/16 for *docker0* , then further 172.18.0.0/16 or as it was configured), one can correlate this with information from Docker to figure out the actual destination container.